# GNOME Extensions do not install on Debian

Tags: debian, gnome, gnome-shell, flatpak

I'm trying to install true-color-invert available at the [GNOME Extensions website](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3530/true-color-invert/) or [similar tools](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/743252/530603). It does not appear in the Extensions application on my Debian nor the `gnome-extensions list` which returns "Extension... Does Not Exists".

1. downloaded for shell version 3.38 extension version 11, because `gnome-shell --version` returns `GNOME Shell version is 3.38.6`.
2. unzipped, and made sure the directory of the unzipped files had the [same name as the `uuid` in `metadata.json`](https://itsfoss.com/gnome-shell-extensions/#method-4-install-gnome-shell-extensions-manually-for-intermediate-to-advanced-users-): `true-color-invert@jackkenney`.
3. moved the directory to the folder of [system-wide extensions](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/gnome-shell-extensions/): `/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/`, where I also affirmed the location of extensions readily appearing in the Extensions application.
4. reboot

What am I missing?

edit 1. I also tried creating the directory `~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/` and putting the extension here.

edit 2. `gnome-extensions install true-color-invertjackkenney.v11.shell-extension.zip` [5](https://askubuntu.com/questions/196884/how-to-install-gnome-shell-extensions-offline) gave similar result as edit 1. did make the extension available.

Other report similar issues. [6](https://www.reddit.com/r/gnome/comments/rbl85n/comment/hnp5sqe/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) [7](https://superuser.com/q/1691843/1183393)

edit 3. it also does not install using preinstalled `chrome-gnome-shell` and the to-be installed browser extension for Firefox, although the website prompts "Your native host connector do not support following APIs: v6." that some say nevertheless should [not be an issue on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/1419146/1688470).

edit 4. I tried multiple different extensions on the GNOME web. None worked. Someone has written at [program at github](https://github.com/8Ten10/Fix-Gnome-Extensions-Your-native-host-connector-do-not-support-following-APIs-v6-) that [arguably fixes it](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chrome-gnome-shell/+bug/1983851/comments/8), but I am a bit hesitant.

edit 5. tried installing flatpak, then Extension Manager. But packages still won't install.

Comment: Could be a permissions issue. Have you checked them/tried chmodding?

Comment: @telometto thanks for commenting. I’m quite new with linux, so it would be very helpful would you be more specific?

Comment: Sure! Open a terminal and do a `stat --format '%a' /path/to/folder`, this will give you the numeric value of the permissions of the folder (e.g. `644`). If the permissions aren't set properly, you can change them by using `chmod -R +x /path/to/folder`. *NOTE:* `+x` gives execute permissions on everything inside the folder, so it may impose a security risk, so be aware. Alternatively, you could check for discrepancies among the ownerships of all the subdirs inside the extension dir by using `ls -la` and eventually just `chown -R yourUser:yourGroup /path/to/folder`.

Comment: Thanks @telometto, would you run this on the directory in which files to be installed are? such as `.deb` files, zip` files or `unzip`ped files? `stat --format '%a /path/to/directory'` returns 755.